# Generating the list of random numbers with certain average difference

Tags: java, php, c, algorithm, random

I have to generate a list of random numbers and they have to have a given average difference. For example, a given average difference is 10, so these numbers are good: `1 3 5 9 15 51`. What I do, is multiply the given average difference by 2 and add 1. Like this:

```
    while (i <= 50000)
    {
        i += Math.random() * givenAverageDiff * 2 + 1;
        list.add(i);
    }
```

But I never get 5000 or more. In fact, it's always 4,850 or less. Why? Let's say `givenAverageDiff` is 10. What's my mistake? How can I fix it?

P.S. Implementation in C or PHP is also good for me.

Comment: What is "average difference"?

Comment: I wonder if there are type conversions messing with things. I assume `i` is an `int`. Is `givenAverageDiff` an `int` or a `double`?

Comment: @Eddy_Em I think that means that the sequence of M items is increasing, and the sum of (i_n+1 - i_n) for n=0 to M-1 = (avg_difference) * (M-1). I don't see how you can guarantee this and also keep any semblance of randomness.

Comment: I just tried running this loop, and it ran just fine for me. Can you show us more context?

Comment: It runs fine, but the result is incorrect. It doesn't have correct average difference.

Comment: So tell us more about the requirements. Do you need it to have exactly the correct average difference each time?

Comment: Yes, that would be great if possible.

Comment: Your question is still incomplete, what do you mean by average difference? is it this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_difference ? if it is then your sequence `1 3 5 9 15 51` would have an average difference of 5.8 and not 10.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks. In that case we can do quite simple: take 1 for first number and then get every n-th number as $i_n = i_{n-1} + R$, where $R$ is random number from 1 to 19 with uniform distribution.

Comment: Why not just use `i += givenAverageDiff * 2`? In this case, E[X(n) - X(n-1)] = E[2*givenAverageDiff*Unif(0,1)] = 2*givenAverageDiff*0.5 = givenAverageDiff

Comment: one question - do you want truly random sequence or only increasing random sequence? I see that your `list` contains increasing values.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing "+ 1".

Let us calculate the expected difference:

E(2*10*x+1)= 2*10*E(x)+1 = 2*10*0.5+1 = 10+1. So, on an average you will get 50000/11 numbers.

You need to pick something whose expected value is equal to 10. Change it to the following and it should work:

```
while (i <= 50000)
    {
        i += Math.random() * (givenAverageDiff-1) * 2 + 1;
        list.add(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about it in terms of the ranges you create. With your current calculation,

```
i += Math.random() * givenAverageDiff * 2 + 1;
```

you are adding between 1 and 2*`givenAverageDiff` to your number. The sum of 1 through 2x is (2x)(2x+1)/2, and since there are 2x options we divide by 2x to get (2x)(2x+1)/(2*2x) = (2x+1)/2 = x + 0.5.

So what you want is to have 2x+1 options, which is easiest by using a range of [0,2*x]. You can get that by adding parenthesis:

```
i += Math.random() * (givenAverageDiff * 2 + 1);
```

If you want it to always increase, then you either need use a non-uniform distribution, or a uniform distribution with a smaller range. To get a range [n,2*x-n] use

```
i += Math.random() * ((givenAverageDiff - n) * 2 + 1) + n;
```

If you use a negative value for `n` you can widen the range, making it possible for numbers to decrease as well.